# how to install an app without jailbreak and use appStore

Tags: ios, iphone

Today i was searching on web about is my iPhone 6 Use MLC Or TLC Nand Flash Memory. And found IOKitBrowser app. Its website and it doesn't redirect to appstore.

[IOKitBrowser](http://www.pgyer.com/IOKitBrowser)

I enter this page with my phone. And click install button. After ask my permission it download / install... I wonder how?..

Thank you

Comment: how this guy make this happen? Enter this website with your iphone(safari) and tap the install button. Then This app will installed and can run on your phone. Is this a big bug for IOS appstore? With this method we dont need developer license for publish our app. I really wonder how he success to do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The developer is using an enterprise distribution certificate (most likely a forged one). Enterprise certificates are only intended to be used to allow companies to internally distribute their apps to employees. The developer is breaking the rules and could be doing bad things to your device.

[Enterprise distribution](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)

Comment: oh thats the answer...:)  I didnt think the enterprise dev program... And yeah i know it might doing bad things to my phone. I load my back up after try this app... Thank you